# Delete ServiceM8 Default Jobs

Tags: servicem8

I'm using the ServiceM8 Rest API with PHP and retrieving the jobs from ServiceM8 that are `Work Orders`.

There is a job named: SAMPLE in there that doesn't appear in the app but are retrieved by the API.

I've tried using the API Delete with the associated Job UUID but it seems to auto-restore.

Has anyone else found this and worked out how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is ever deleted in ServiceM8. Rather, the visibility of an object/record is controlled by a field called 'active', with 1 = active (visible), and 0 = archived (not visible).

'Deleting' something in ServiceM8 is done by setting the 'active' field for that object/record to '0'. Then, for instance, when doing a search to return all 'active' jobs, filter the active to = 1. When doing a search for 'deleted' jobs, filter to = 0.

Comment: Thanks - I worked this out myself several weeks ago, but didn't update my question.